# How to fix one or more indexers are invalid error in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm getting an error in Magento:

> One or more indexers are invalid

I tried this in the command prompt:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

but when I do, I get this error:

[image]

I'm not familiar with Windows; I'm used to working on a Ubuntu terminal.

please check the Magento dashboard error below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP CLI as its called ( php for the Command Line Interface ) is called php.exe It lives in `c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.x.y\php.exe` ( where x and y are the version numbers of php that you have installed )

If you want to create php scrips to run from the command line then great its easy and very useful.

Create yourself a batch file like this, lets call it phppath.cmd :

```
PATH=%PATH%;c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.x.y
php -v
```

Save this into one of your folders that is already on your PATH, so you can run it from anywhere.

Now from a command window, cd into your source folder and run >phppath.

Then run

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

It should work like a dream.

Comment: thank you bro :) you saved my day ! :) thank you once again. learned new thing today

Comment: PHP script is running but the alert is still on dashboard.. do i have any idea about this bro.. i cleared cache files from var folder

Comment: It could be that ist takes a while.
Or are the any other Errors in the CMD window?

Answer (score 0):

just create your folder path and add "bin" directory For example :

> c:\wamp\www\Magento2.0\bin>

and execute below command for reindex all indexes.

```
php magento indexer:reindex
```