# Magento Error "One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running."

Tags: magento, magento2

When I try to install Magento to Localhost it gives the below error:

> One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is
> running.

[image]

I have tried the following to re-index the Indexer -

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

But it did not work. Why is this error happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix one or more indexers are invalid error in Magento?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177542/how-to-fix-one-or-more-indexers-are-invalid-error-in-magento)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity- Don't you think that We need programming in Magento when editing.

Answer (score 3):

open magento folder and hold shift +right click ->use command window here and then write :-

**php bin/magento indexer:reindex**

and hit enter wait for some time to process

Answer (score 1):

To reindex in Magento 2, go to the `CLI` and then the `root folder` of your Magento installation and run the below command :

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reindex all of indexes using cmd command.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

For more command please find over http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html

This is not an error, whenever you install magento it requires to build indexes.

Comment: And can you please tell me how to add a downloaded theme to Magento. Please help me with this. I am new to Magento and already search many docs online but did not find any answer.

Comment: When I run the above command given by you it gives:  'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You have to set your php program in environment path variable or use path to php.exe in place of php in this command.